# visual studio was unable to create a secure connection azurewebsites:4020 authentication failed

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, sitecore8, sitecore-commerce-server

[image]

I get this pop and error for authencation failure azurewebsites.net:4020 error. Due to this i am unable to log in to my website.
I don't know what to do and how  to handle this.

Kindly suggest  and help me

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Comment: No i didn't find any answer..

Answer (score 0):

After searching various other solutions, what did work in the end was installing the "Azure Development Workload" of Visual Studio (using the Visual Studio Installer), then with your project loaded in VS, open "Server Explorer", expand the Azure tab and simply navigate to your web app, right-click and Attach debugger.

[image]

Check that you have enabled debugging in Azure for the App.
This bypasses the remote debugging, and its security credentials.

Comment: How to enable debugging in Azure for App Service in 2021 (Dockerized .NET 5 app)? I can't see this option

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio -> right click -> run administrator

Comment: It's never a good idea to give admistrator rights to such tools. This is a massive security breach. There's always a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

For me, what fixed it, was changing the site URL from `http` to `https`.

[image]

Then I could attach the debugger:

[image]

[image]

All in VS 2022.